# angularjs one or more custom popup in all pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup

My angularjs app has one or more quick links in all pages, each quick links need to show popup window.
Each popup has its own html, controller and service. 
So, how to implement this, there are more than one popups which may need to display in most of the pages. popup must appear above the current view and should leave focus to below page after closing the popup.

also please advice me how to loaded these controllers and service JS files by Lazy Loading (Resolve).

is it possible to implement this by adding a extra ui-view for modal popup.

Comment: uibootstrap which is built for angular has this functionality built in. Please read their documentation they even have a $modal service which will handle the code templates.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the same using stick state Modal of UI-Router Extras

```
https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras
```

demo link

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/qgt0RkEnXDPDTdMJPIfy?p=preview
```